# Orion 1.3 crash with GET request on root (http://server:port/)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

in the new version 1.3 of ORION if I make a GET http request on the root of the server, the broker immediately breaks down.

I set the logs at DEBUG level and de trace levels to 0-255, the execution seems to be correct. There is no trace which help us undestand what is happening before the crash.

We tried in diferent ORION installations(docker from docker HUB, on CENTos OVM)

Anyone knows what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test and I can confirm that this is a bug. A recent change in the detection of the API version uses the URI PATH without first checking for empty URI PATH. The result is a segmentation fault. The fix is more than easy. Will be fixed in the next few days and included in the next release (1.4.0).

Comment: Fixed in develop branch. See https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/2528